# Cut/paste from/to contenteditable to itself does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, copy-paste, contenteditable

Try to run this simple code, give the text the focus, select all the text (CTRL+A), cut it (CTRL+X), and paste it (CTRL+V). Strangely, the text is not pasted. Why?

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="mytext">Hello world</span>
```

**How to enable normal copy/cut/paste features in `contenteditable` elements ?**

*Note : the problem is present (at least) for Firefox 32/Win 7.  Not present with Chrome, nor IE10, nor Safari (tested on Windows).*

Comment: @Juhana, have you tried with Firefox ?

Comment: Seems fixed as of 39 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a Firefox bug :**
see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858918

when you copy paste into the span, it actually copies the span itself, but not the node text contained.
You can see it by assigning a border to spans :

```css
    span {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="mytext">Hello world</span>
```

**As a workaround**,
You may want to change your `span` to `p` or other html tag that doesn't behave like that.

:Aryeh Gregor should be working on it right now and he already published [patches](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858918#attachment_table).

*Ps : Confirmed on Firefox 32.0.3 and Nightly Build 33.0 on osx 10.9.5*
*Pps : Even oddier : when you copy text from `span` and paste it to a `div` (or other non buggy elements) with `contenteditable="true"`, it will add a linebreak, whereas when pasting to text editor with invisibles shown, it only paste the string copied. I don't know how but my guess is that it copies/pastes the `textNode` as a new `textNode`, interpreted as a `string` by other softwares.*

Comment: Right, this seems to be a bug. I changed my `span` to `div` and it works. I don't have a bugzilla account, if you have one, could you post this @Kaiido ?

Comment: I don't either have an account but I'll make one if no one has reported this 'till I have the time.